# Get a piece of Javascript to work on my Jquery slide form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem that has been driving me crazy!

I am using slide in forms for a step by step ordering page for pizza, My javascript makes it so I can specify how many toppings People can click on.
Here is a working example without my site.

http://jsfiddle.net/SQdNQ/195/

This is the javascript actual function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='toppingtypes']").change(function () {
        var maxAllowed = 2;
        var cnt = $("input[name='toppingtypes']:checked").length;
        if (cnt > maxAllowed) {
            $(this).prop("checked", "");
            alert('You can select  ' + maxAllowed + ' Toppings');
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that I cannot get it working on my actual page. 
Here is a Github repository of Some of my code. (Click On The Pizza Button when on index.php)

https://github.com/dhierholzer/onlineordering.git

Note:

- The piece of Javascript is at the bottom of my index page that limits how many boxes can be checked.
- I think it has something to do with my version of jquery being outdated on my webpage but if I try to use updated jquery code, the site breaks.

Please let me know if you can find out why I cant get my javscript to run on the Checkbox form.

Thanks again, please note if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing plenty JS importing.
If you open your console, you will notice that there's a lot of "foobar is not a function".

Once the parser finds an error, the rest of the code won't be executed.

Adding

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js">
</script>
```

before calling custom.js and removing the outer "$([...])" from the line 199 in custom.js like so

```
// fred carousel slider
function fredCarouselSlider() {
    //  Responsive layout, resizing the items
    $('.list_carousel').carouFredSel({
    responsive: true,
    auto: true,
    width: '100%',
    prev: '#prev3',
    next: '#next3',
    scroll: 1,
    items: {
    //width: 400,
    //  height: '30%',  //  optionally resize item-height
    visible: {
    min:3,
    max: 3
    }
    }
    });
};
```

did the trick.

Comment: That makes sense, I made the changes with no such luck though.. I updated the code on my Github, maybe you could look at it and see what is now different. Thanks again!

Comment: _I was going to add a screen shot but I don't have enough reputation_

I'm using Firefox Developer Edition 39, cloned your files here and it all seems to be working fine.

Comment: Did you take a look at my source since I made your changes? was there anything different from what you did? Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("input[name='toppingtypes']").on('change',function () {
 // do Stuff
});
```